# gmail integration in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail

I am working on an ios Application, recently I have got a new requirement for it i.e. to provide user a option to sign in with gmail . when user hit the sign in button then i want to open gmail login screen and after user enter his credentials , if the credentials are correct then instead of open his mail , i want the control to be navigate to my application home page . can anybody tell me how to achieve this

Comment: Hey r u able to integrate gmail into ur app.Please provide me a gud link.I tried ur answer but I get error Error Domain=com.google.GTMOAuth2 Code=-1001..When I go for a differnt code following this link http://technogerms.com/login-with-google-using-oauth-2-0-for-ios-xcode-objective-c/I get access token , but unable to retrieve user details with that access token

Comment: @arizah, what is ur email id , i can send u a sample

Comment: Ok please send  it to the id in profile

Comment: @Kausar u r email id is not visible in ur profile .

Comment: Ok.Please mail to this hajirakausar21@gmail.com

Comment: @RIYAZ Hi i am trying to do the same but not able to get it done successfully.I am not getting any error but its not working properly. can you share some sample code or demo with me please to configure mails to my app.

Comment: @ios yes of course i can share the code , send a test mail to skriyaz7@gmail.com

Comment: @RIYAZ Please Send it to my id  rohan.sdcet@gmail.com

Comment: Hi, I want to integrate gmail in my ios application, Please sugeest me if you have any sample code or link to sugeest. I had asked question here stackoverflow.com/questions/33624136/… . Please answer it If you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution . . .i think this will help anybody else
Follow the below steps to integrate gmail with your application .

**1.Add following classes to you project .**

GTMHTTPFetcher.h , GTMHTTPFetcher.m ,GTMOAuth2Authentication.h, GTMOAuth2Authentication.m,GTMOAuth2SignIn.h,GTMOAuth2SignIn.m,GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h,GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m,GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib,SBJSON.h , SBJSON.m

you will get these classes here : https://github.com/jonmountjoy/Force.com-iOS-oAuth-2.0-Example

**Note** : if you are working under ARC Environment then you have to disable the ARC for following files :
GTMHTTPFetcher.m , GTMOAuth2Authentication.m , GTMOAuth2SignIn.m, GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m

To disable ARC for source files in Xcode 4, select the project and the target in Xcode. Under the target "Build Phases" tab, expand the Compile Sources build phase, select the library source files, then press Enter to open an edit field, and type -fno-objc-arc as the compiler flag for those files.

**2. add the following frameworks**

```
security.framework , systemConfiguration.framework
```

**3. Register your app to google api console …. here :** https://code.google.com/apis/console

Then go to ApiAccess section , create client id for iOS app .
 then you will get clientID, ClientSecret and RedirectUrl

****4. Now it's time for coding  . . . .****
create a signIn button in your controller and set the action for that . Here when the user click the button SignInGoogleButtonClicked method gets called .

```
//import GTMOAuth2Authentication , GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch

#define GoogleClientID    @"paster your client id"
#define GoogleClientSecret @"paste your client secret"
#define GoogleAuthURL   @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
#define GoogleTokenURL  @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

-(void) SignInGoogleButtonClicked
{

 NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:GoogleTokenURL];

    NSString * redirectURI = @"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth;

    auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"google"
                                                             tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                          redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                             clientID:GoogleClientID
                                                         clientSecret:GoogleClientSecret];

    auth.scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewcontroller = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth
                                                                                                authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:GoogleAuthURL]
                                                                                                keychainItemName:@"GoogleKeychainName" delegate:self
                                                                                                finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];

}



//this method is called when authentication finished

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth error:(NSError * )error
{

    if (error != nil) {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Authorizing with Google"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {

         UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert !"
                                                         message:@"success"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this olution step by step but not work not get any error. or also not get the gmail login window for that.

Comment: man the code is working for me , can you just cross check your code once .

Comment: ya this code works fine for me but how i get the details login information like facebook graph api they provide all the details...

Comment: error appeard when login the user  error log is invalide user i am testing this on simulator...

Comment: it working better but i getting error   Error Domain=com.google.GTMOAuth2 Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GTMOAuth2 error -1001.)

Comment: i m getting same problem Error Domain=com.google.GTMOAuth2 Code=-1001

Comment: Hey is the problem of 1001 error solved.If so please provide me how, bcoz Im also facing the same problem

Comment: I think you people should check your #define GoogleAuthURL @"" and
#define GoogleTokenURL @"" ..... these codes are not correct

Comment: @OmerWaqasKhan this are fixed url's provided in oAuth2 documentation provided by google

Comment: Hi, I want to integrate gmail in my ios application, Please sugeest me if you have any sample code or link to sugeest. I had asked question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33624136/retrive-friends-of-friends-in-gmail-for-ios-app Please answer it If you can

Answer (score 0):

I found it. but then i am just able to fetch the snippet i.e first few words of e-mail body & not the whole . I just stopped coz i did not found any other way to do so. because i am using OAuth 2.0 .